# Makefile generated by qmake copy the target files only after a second run

Tags: qt, qmake, nmake

I have a Qt library project and I want to install some files in a specific folder.

The *"MyLib.pro"* project file is:

```
...
win32 {
    CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
        libFiles.files = $$OUT_PWD/release/MyLib.lib
        libFiles.path = $$PWD/../staticlib/release
    }

    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        libFiles.files = $$OUT_PWD/debug/MyLib.lib
        libFiles.files += $$OUT_PWD/debug/MyLib.pdb
        libFiles.path = $$PWD/../staticlib/debug
    }

    headerFiles.files = $$PWD/MyLib.h
    headerFiles.path = $$PWD/../staticlib/include
}


!isEmpty(libFiles.path) {
    INSTALLS += libFiles
}

!isEmpty(headerFiles.path) {
    INSTALLS += headerFiles
}
```

Using QtCreator and adding a new build step *"make install"* all works fine and the library built is installed into the specified path given the specified build.

If I want to do the same using the command line like below

```
cd %PATH_TO_LIB_SRC%
cd ..
mkdir build
cd build
qmake "CONFIG+=debug_and_release" ../src/MyLib.pro
nmake -f Makefile.Debug
nmake -f MakeFile.Debug install
```

the *install* command copy only the header file. If I re-run the `qmake` and the `nmake` command, repeating the `nmake install` command now copies also the library files.

Concluding, the only solution that I found is to repeat the commands like below:

```
...
qmake "CONFIG+=debug_and_release" ../src/MyLib.pro
nmake -f Makefile.Debug
nmake -f Makefile.Release
qmake "CONFIG+=debug_and_release" ../src/MyLib.pro
nmake -f Makefile.Debug
nmake -f Makefile.Release
nmake -f MakeFile.Debug install
nmake -f MakeFile.Release install
```

What I'm wronging? I'm missing something like *QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS* or *POST_TARGETDEPS*?

**UPDATE:**

I compared the "Makefile", "Makefile.Debug" "Makefile.Release" of the first and the second run and:

- "Makefile" are the same
- for "Makefile.Debug" and "Makefile.Release", the new ones have only the install instruction for the .lib and .pcb files. I report the difference below.

```
...
+ ####### Install

+ install_libFiles: first FORCE
+   @if not exist C:$(INSTALL_ROOT)\libs\MyLib\build\..\staticlib\debug mkdir C:$(INSTALL_ROOT)\libs\MyLib\build\..\staticlib\debug & if not exist C:$(INSTALL_ROOT)\libs\MyLib\build\..\staticlib\debug exit 1
+   $(QINSTALL) C:\libs\MyLib\build\debug\MyLib.lib ...

...

+ uninstall_libFiles: FORCE
+   -$(DEL_FILE) C:$(INSTALL_ROOT)\libs\MyLib\build\..\staticlib\debug\MyLib.pdb

... 

install: +install_libFiles+ install_headerFiles  FORCE

uninstall: +uninstall_libFiles+ uninstall_headerFiles  FORCE
```

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of your Makefile after each call to qmake? Are there differences between the first and second run?

Comment: I checked and there are differences only for "Makefile.Debug" and "Makefile.Release" (not in "Makefile" file). After the second run the files contain the install instructions like:
```####### Install

install libFiles: first FORCE  #if not exist C:$(INSTALL_ROOT)\ ...

uninstall libFiles: FORCE -$(DEL_FILE) ...

install: install_libFiles install_headerFiles FORCE
```